# how to use Oauth connector in mule?

Tags: oauth

I'm very new to mulesoft and anypoint platform. can anybody please guide me about how to use  Oauth connector in mule and also how to apply Oauth 2.0 policy to api?
 thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/using-a-connector-to-access-an-oauth-api

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the document to understand about policy. https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/introduction-to-policy-management.

Using OAuth Connector needs the parameters which is required for any OAuth. Client secret, client id, etc. So please have a look into it.